# Allow user to drop only tables / views created by that user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, drop-table

Is it possible to allow a user to *only* drop tables and views that he/she created in MySQL? How is this achieved?

Comment: Did you in fact observe that a non-root user could drop tables and views created by other users?

Comment: No. I haven't tried dropping tables / views I *didn't* create. If I have drop privileges but I am not a root user, does this mean I can *only* drop tables I create?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a dedicated MySQL instance per user (with docker for example) and let them do whatever they want. Your situation maybe different, of course, I'm just sharing an idea.